# Question about Egorov's theorem and $L^p$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Q) Let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $X$, $0<p<\infty, f\in L^p(\mu),f_n\in L^p(\mu), f_n(x)\to f(x)$ a.e. and $||f_n||_p\to ||f||_p$. Show that $\lim ||f_n-f||_p\to 0$ by completing the following $2$ steps:

Let me look at step $1$ for now.
$1$) By Egorov's theorem, $X=A\cup B$ in such a way that $\int_A |f|^p < \epsilon, \mu(B)<\infty$, and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $B$. Apply Fatou's lemma to $\int_B|f_n|^p$ to show

$$\limsup \int_A|f_n|^pd\mu\leq \epsilon$$

Firstly, I know Egorov's theorem as: If $\mu(X)<\infty$, then $\exists A\subset X$, s.t. $\mu(A)<\epsilon$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $X\setminus A$. So I don't understand how $\int_A |f|^p < \epsilon$ leads to a similar result?

Secondly, how can I apply Fatou's lemma to $\int_B|f_n|^p$ to get:

$$\limsup \int_A|f_n|^pd\mu\leq \epsilon$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{B}\lim_{n}|f_{n}|^{p}&\leq\liminf_{n}\int_{B}|f_{n}|^{p}\\
&=\liminf_{n}\left(\int_{X}|f_{n}|^{p}-\int_{A}|f_{n}|^{p}\right)\\
&=\|f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}+\liminf_{n}\left(-\int_{A}|f_{n}|^{p}\right)\\
&=\|f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}-\limsup_{n}\int_{A}|f_{n}|^{p},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n}\int_{A}|f_{n}|^{p}\leq\|f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}-\int_{B}|f|^{p}=\int_{A}|f|^{p}<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

For the first part:

Given $\epsilon>0$, since $|f|^{p}\in L^{1}$, by the absolute continuity of integral one has some $\delta>0$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{S}|f|^{p}<\epsilon/2,~~~~\mu(S)<\delta.
\end{align*}
Now it is clear that
\begin{align*}
\int|f|^{p}=\lim_{N}\int_{|f|^{p}\geq 1/2^{N}}|f|^{p},
\end{align*}
then for some $N$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{|f|^{p}<1/2^{N}}|f|^{p}=\int|f|^{p}-\int_{|f|^{p}\geq 1/2^{N}}|f|^{p}<\epsilon/2.
\end{align*}
But we also have
\begin{align*}
\alpha^{p}\mu(|f|^{p}\geq\alpha)\leq\|f\|_{L^{p}}<\infty,
\end{align*}
in particular, we have $\mu(|f|^{p}\geq 1/2^{N})<\infty$. Applying Egorov to $(|f|^{p}\geq 1/2^{N})$ we have some $B\subseteq(|f|^{p}\geq 1/2^{N})$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\mu((|f|^{p}\geq 1/2^{N})-B)<\delta
\end{align*}
and that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly in $B$. Set $A=((|f|^{p}\geq 1/2^{N})-B)\cup(|f|^{p}<1/2^{N})$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{A}|f|^{p}=\int_{(|f|^{p}\geq 1/2^{N})-B}|f|^{p}+\int_{|f|^{p}<1/2^{N}}|f|^{p}<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon.
\end{align*}

**The proof of the so called absolute continuity:**

We will prove that, for $g\in L^{1}$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that for every measurable set $S$ with $\mu(S)<\delta$, one has $\displaystyle\int_{S}|g|<\epsilon$. Then the above case is just a realization of $g$ to $|f|^{p}$.

Note that $|g|<\infty$ a.e. and hence $|g|\chi_{|g|\leq M}\uparrow|g|$ a.e. and hence 
\begin{align*}
\int_{|g|>M}|g|=\int|g|-\int|g|\chi_{|g|\leq M}<\epsilon/2
\end{align*}
for some $M>0$.

Then for any measurable set $S$ with $\mu(S)\leq\epsilon/(2M)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{S}|g|&=\int_{S\cap(|g|\leq M)}|g|+\int_{S\cap(|g|>M)}|g|\\
&\leq M\int_{S\cap(|g|\leq M)}+\int_{|g|>M}|g|\\
&<M\int_{S}+\epsilon/2\\
&=M\mu(S)+\epsilon/2\\
&<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
The $\delta>0$ can be taken as $\epsilon/(2M)$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101201/discussion-on-answer-by-user284331-question-about-egorovs-theorem-and-lp-con).